Voter Count(similar to Bertrands ballot theorem)
This question is from Quantguide: Voter Mayhem2:
Two candidates, say
A and
B, are running for office. Candidate
A received
n votes, while Candidate
B received
m votes, with
n>m. The
n+m votes are thrown into a box and shuffled around. Then, the votes are drawn without replacement one-by-one. A running tally of the number of votes for each candidate is kept. The probability that Candidate
A is never behind in the voting count.
According to me it is similar to the case of moving on a grid from point (0,0) to (n,m) without crossing the line $y=\frac{m}{n+m}x$. Hence the probability which I was getting is:
$\frac{n+1-m}{n+1}$. But this is showing to be wrong answer.

Why is it "without crossing the line $y=\frac{m}{n+m}x$" rather than "without crossing the line $y=x$"?

You are correct, the probability is $(n+1-m)/(n+1)$.

@Henry coz we're not sure whether n==m.

@MikeEarnest But this answer is wrong according to QuantGuide

Quantguide is wrong, then. This is the second time I’ve seen a question on mathstackexchange asking about a quantguide problem/solution where their claimed solution turned out to be wrong. Here is the first: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4767062/177399

Wikipedia confirms your answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed

I think there’s nothing to answer here, so I vote to close this question.
